# What's an inexpensive way to measure the amount of UV light (or IR light) given off by a light bulb?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, measurements, infrared-radiation

What's an inexpensive way to measure the amount of UV light (or IR light) given off by a light bulb? Specifically, the amount at various wavelengths of UV (and IR)?

Comment: Do you mean "inexpensive" like a few thousand dollars? Or a few dollars? Or what?

Comment: How far into the UV and IR do you want to go? What wavelength resolution do you want?  What kind of lightbulbs are you interested in: incandescent, fluorescent, LED? Why are you interested in measuring the UV and IR?

Comment: Is this related to your previous questions? If so, maybe just use a sensitive thermometer and some optical short pass and long pass filters. Or try a pyroelectric sensor and filters. Pyroelectric sensors are available with relatively flat responses over the range 190 nm to 20 microns.

Comment: Please edit to specify your desired wavelength coverage range and whether you want qualitative or quantitative detection/measurement capability. A typical consumer camera (or smartphone camera) may (or does) have filters that greatly attenuate UV and near IR.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that there is a cheap attachment lens and app for a cellphone camera that will turn it into a spectrophotometer, but I do not know where to look for it.